# NodeJS server randomly ends with "Terminated: 15" but no other information to find where/why

Tags: node.js

I have a NodeJS server running locally on my system, with the following dependencies

```
"express": "^4.17.1",
"request-promise": "^4.2.6",
"socket.io": "^1.3.7",
"socket.io-client": "^1.3.7",
"ws": "^7.4.1"
```

Some of the aforementioned dependencies are deprecated or outdated, but I'm working on sorting them out. In the mean time, the server is continuously running and receiving data from a web stream.

Normally it will run for days at a time until I terminate it, but three times now it has ended on its own with a single-line message:

```
Terminated: 15
```

I have no idea where this is coming from or what is causing it. This most recent one occurred after only a couple hours of running, which is much less than the longest multi-day run.

Is there any way to sleuth and find out what is causing this, or what line is triggering it? It happens so infrequently that it's basically impossible to test for, but it's one of the biggest issues I need to sort out.

According to [this article on exiting Node](https://stackabuse.com/how-to-exit-in-node-js/), I can use `process.kill(process.pid);` to exit with the same "Terminated: 15" message. But I have searched every document in the directory, and not a single one of them has a `.kill` in it, nevermind `process.kill`.

Any tips on figuring out what's going on would be greatly appreciated. Much thanks!

Comment: Could it be the problem with the hardware? (insufficient RAM or something like that). Is your server secure and no one, but you have access?

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaĐinh It isn't a resource-heavy code, or at least it shouldn't be. I'll throw in a line of code to output the memory usage, but I don't expect I'll see anything more than a few MB. And the server is secure, it only runs locally.

Comment: Are you logging the errors? It can help to atleast check some of the details. Also, are you handling the 'uncaught exceptions' ?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara, typically I print errors to the screen, but I'll set up a log file to store all logs. I haven't been doing any global (`process`) exception handling, but I'll add it in as well. Hopefully one of these will turn something up.

Comment: Definitely, I believe at least we can get something when and what is causing this to happen.